# vk_api python , 2fa создание ответа что бы подделаться под приложение Android

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, response, 2fa

товарищи, требуется помощь с созданием запроса для двухфакторной аутентификации, в ответ на авторизацию приходит такой ответ:

```
{'error': 'need_validation', 'error_description': 'open redirect_uri in browser [5]. Also you can use 2fa_supported param', 'validation_type': '2fa_app', 'validation_sid': '2fa_...', 'phone_mask': '+7 *** *** ** **', 'redirect_uri': 'https://m.vk.com/login?act=authcheck&api_hash=...}
```

при получении данных с ссылки приходит страница с полем для ввода кода, часть страницы, которая приходит и (как я понял отвечает за ввод кода):

```
<h3 class="slim_header">Проверка безопасности</h3>
  <div class="form_item">
      <div class="fi_row">Пожалуйста, введите <b>код</b> из личного сообщения от Администрации или из приложения для генерации кодов, чтобы подтвердить, что вы владелец страницы.</div>
    <form method="post" action="/login?act=authcheck_code&hash=1631990925_f80ca8734d14ad7645" novalidate>
      <dl class="fi_row">
  <dt class="fi_label">Код подтверждения:</dt>
  <dd>
    <div class="iwrap"><input type="tel" name="code" class="textfield" autocomplete="one-time-code" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" /></div>
    <div class="fi_subrow">    <label class="option_row " onclick="">
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="remember" value="1" checked="checked" />
      <span class="option_label" >Запомнить браузер</label>
    </label></div>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

если сделать всё вручную на странице, то перенаправляет на ссылку с токеном и секретом, но через программу у меня так и не получилось получить заветные токен и секрет, т.к при любом сделанном мной запросе отправляет обратно на эту же страницу, но с другим хэшем , пример с моим говно-кодом и(как мне кажется, просто неверным запросом), делал как это реализовано в самом vk_api:

```
code = input('Put your 2fa code here: ')
    savesession = 1
    auth_hash = ''
    print(auth_hash)
    values = {
            'al': '1',
            'code': code,
            'hash': auth_hash,
            'remember': int(savesession),
        }
    response = session.post(
            url,
            values
        )
    input(response.text)
    data = json.loads(response.text.lstrip('<!--'))
    status = data['payload'][0]
    if status == '4':  # OK
        path = json.loads(data['payload'][1][0])
    return token,secret
```

Answer (score 0):

Не самым простым , но так называемым решением 'В лоб' оказалось применение selenium и работа со страницами, если кто-то таки найдёт более изящное решение, просим.
пример рабочей программы:

1. проверяем ответ, если пришёл такой, как мне:

```
if answer['error'] == 'need_validation':
                print('Вк собака отправляет на двухфакторку погодь чутка, прожка старается не отвалится')
                response = this.session.get(answer['redirect_uri'])
                this.token , this.secret = fa_handler(answer['redirect_uri'])
```

2. Сама функция обработки:

```
def fa_handler(url):
    option = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    #Почему headless = False , спросите вы, дело в том, что может ещё отправить на капчу и как вернуть видимость если такое произошло я способа не нашёл
    option.headless = False
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(options = option)
    browser.get(url)
    codexpath = '/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/form/dl/dd/div[1]/input'
    buttonxpath = '/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/input'
    code = str(input('2fa code here: '))
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(codexpath).send_keys(code)
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(buttonxpath).click()
    link = browser.current_url
    if link.find('access_token=') != -1:
        token = link[link.find('access_token=')+len('access_token='):link.find('&user_id=')]
        secret = link[link.find('&secret=')+len('&secret='):]
    else:
        print('Аахахаха вводи капчу, stupid robot')
        link = captcha_handler(browser)
        token = link[link.find('access_token=')+len('access_token='):link.find('&user_id=')]
        secret = link[link.find('&secret=')+len('&secret='):]
    return token , secret
```

3. Обработка капчи, потом можно будет просто в приложение выгружать картинку капчи или автоматизировать это:

```
def captcha_handler(browser):
    print('Это тестовая функция - работай ручками')
    codexpath = '/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/form/div[2]/div/input'
    buttonxpath = '/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/form/div[3]/input'
    # xpath на картинку капчи /html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/form/div[1]/img
    code = str(input('captcha code here: '))
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(codexpath).send_keys(code)
    browser.find_element_by_xpath(buttonxpath).click()
    link = browser.current_url
    input(link)
    return link
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [справке](/help/how-to-ask).